# Mocking framework for .Net fx 1.1?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, .net-1.1

Anyone have any ideas what I can do?

Please reserve commenting about using 1.1 still, it's out of my hands :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rhino Mocks** is supposed to be compatible with the framework 1.1, according to their website.
It is a really good mocking framework, once you get used to it

Have a look here to see what you'll be able to do, and what you won't be able to do:

ayende.com/Wiki/(S(lqa0ob552sfbu545c5ss4b55))/Rhino+Mocks+Generics.ashx

Comment: wow, i had wrongly assumed it would be incompatible.  excellent news!

Comment: Actually, it has some cool generic features you won't be able to use with .net 1.1. But still you can mock interfaces and classes as usual.
I have been using it extensively these past months for Unit Testing, and I must admit, Rhino Mocks is great :)

Comment: It looks like as of v3 Rhino Mocks is .2.0+, but I can live with that

Comment: Yes, I guess you have to stick with version 2.9.6, released in December 2006.
Still, it is better than nothing, and it will work just as fine I suppose, for 1.1 ;)

Comment: Unable to find any download link, i am also looking for some mocking framework for .net 1.1

Answer (score 1):

I use both [NMock2](http://www.nmock.org/) and an older version of [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/learn_about_typemock_isolator.php) at work when dealing with our legacy products that only run on 1.1.