# Rhino Mocks on Visual Studio 2003 with .Net Framework 1.1

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, visual-studio-2003

Reading articles on the Internet I can see that Rhino Mocks is compatible with .Net Framework 1.1. But when I try to reference Rhino.Mocks.dll in Visual Studio 2003 I get the following error:

> A reference to
>   'C:\Projects\Bayer\NovaExtranet\src\CHANGE-PDB-DEV\Portal\Assemblies\Rhino.Mocks.dll'
>   could not be added. This is not a valid assembly or COM component. 
>   Only assemblies with extension 'dll' and COM components can be
>   referenced.  Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it
>   is a valid assembly or COM component.

I'm using Rhino Mocks version 3.6 that I downloaded from:
http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/downloads/rhino-mocks/latest

How do I make use of Rhino Mocks in VS2003 .Net 1.1? Should I download an older version of Rhino.Mocks.dll?

Answer (score 0):

As of V3, it supports 2.0 (mentioned [Mocking framework for .Net fx 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914960/mocking-framework-for-net-fx-1-1)).  So using this, you may be able to find an older version.

Comment: According to a user comment in the post you mentioned, version 2.9.6 targets framework 1.1. Thanks!